# How can i get properties from template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can i get properties from template before send request to server about the data?
Here's my template:

```
<box-component inline-template>
<div>
    <div class="loading" v-if="Loading">  Loading ...  </div>
    <div  v-if="Result">
        <ul>
            <li> {{ Result.FirstProp }} </li>
            <li> {{ Result.FourthProp }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my component:

```
let BoxComponent = {
data() {
    return {            
        Result: null,
        Loading: true
    };
},
created: function () {
    this.Update();
},
methods: {
    Update: function () {
        this.Loading = true;    
        axios.post("#SERVER_URL#")
            .then(response => {
                this.Loading = false;
                this.Result = response.data;
            });
         }
}
}
 Vue.component('box-component', BoxComponent);
```

It's works fine! The problem is the server response contain much more data. Server response:

```
{
    "FirstProp": "first",
    "SecondProp": "second"
     ...
    "HundredthProp": "hudredth"
}
```

I can't modify the response (other project use this too). But if i am able to send property list from the template (which are in this case FirstProp and FourthProp) the server side give me the filtered response which contains only these properties becouse the optimal response look like this:

```
{
    "FirstProp": "first",
    "FourthProp": "fourth"
}
```

So, the question is: how can i do that?

Can i find it in the Vue object?

I can load template as a string variable, but i want to avoid regex hack.

Update:

[In this case, BoxTemplate call server side without "filters"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLvEI.png)

[This is the optimal case, when js get the variables, that the template use, and call with them the server side. In this case, in the response there are only that variables, what template really use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE9p2.png)

Comment: what exactly is the issue, you have nothing dynamic here. You have used `FirstProp` and `FourthProp` in your component, so I don't see why you can't do like in the answer which was provided to you.

Comment: I have to use the same conponent to different projects. Another project maybe call component with this template: <ul> <li> {{ Result.FifthProp }} </li> <li> {{ Result.ThirdProp }} </li> </ul>  I can use mixin and set all of the data for different projects, but it is not too flexible

Comment: Still don't understand, that is not dynamic, if you actually code those props in template, then you are aware of which props you need. I assume this is not your "real" scenario, so maybe there is an issue with that in your question.

Comment: There are two project. They use the same component ( BoxComponent.js), they call the same server side. But the projects use different template with different variables. I need to call the server side with thecurrent template variables

Comment: in my case there are close to hundred projects exits and the server give ~200 variables in the response. This is why neccessary, that the js call the server with the current variables.
i can't set the variables names in the "data(){}" with each project, but 
when component call the server, i have to know what variables exist in the template. I don't know, that how can i do this in vuejs.

Comment: well, if you still have hardcoded those props in your template, why don't pass them to the `box-component`?

Comment: I am not really understand how you mean. I don't know how can read  the template variables from the js file. The component in js get the variables from the server and pass them to the template, but  it is lot of variable and i want only that variables, what exist in the  template.

Comment: In your image, your component Project A with Template A has `FirstProp` and `FourthProp` **hard**coded in template, so that should mean that since you are coding those properties, you are aware that you need those props in your box-component, therefore pass them as props to box-component.

Comment: So it's not about reading the template. You, as the coder are coding `FirstProp` and `FourthProp` in the template, so those are the properties you need. Not dynamic here at all. Just pass the properties you need to `box-component`: `<box-component inline-template :myProps="["FirstProp", "FourthProp"]">`. Then box component can make the ajax call based on the values in the array. So box-component is a dumb component and just takes the array fed to it.

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me, that i don't have to set props in the js. but, the final goal is, that i won't set these props in :myProps. Becouse these props number are somewhere 50, and this can be source of problem on the frontend side. I am understand, that if it's can not be done and
this is the only way in vue js.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how is set up your back-end but you can have additional property within your data:

```
data() {
    return { 
        listOfProperty: [
            'FirstProp',
            'FourthProp',
        ],
...
```

And use list of it to send data to server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is the data have to be dynamic. Multiple project can call the same component with different template.